# how to make changes in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an existing database which works fine and I need to add some changes in it. The db is not working after those changes. How should I alter the db in order to keep the existing and add new changes? Any help is appreciated. Here is the original db

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DATABASE_NAME.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "POSITION_TABLE";
    private static final String _ID = "_id";
    private static final String RADIO_BUTTON_POSITION = "radio_button_position";


    public DBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String create_table = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( "
                + "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,"
                + RADIO_BUTTON_POSITION + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + _ID + " TEXT NOT NULL)";
        db.execSQL(create_table);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop Table if exists " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }


    }

      public boolean updateButtonPosition(String _id,String radio_button_position){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String selection = "_id = ?";
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(_ID,_id);
        contentValues.put(RADIO_BUTTON_POSITION,radio_button_position);
        long result = database.update(TABLE_NAME , contentValues , _ID + " =? " ,
                new String[]{_id});
        if (result == -1){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }


    }

      public int readButtonPosition(String _id,String radio_button_position)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + RADIO_BUTTON_POSITION + " FROM "
                +TABLE_NAME+" WHERE " + _ID +" =? " , new String[] {String.valueOf(_id)});
       
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            return cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(RADIO_BUTTON_POSITION));
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

This is the new additions that I want to add in the above db.

```
private static final String LAST_NO = "LAST_NO";

public boolean updateNumber(String _id,int last_no){
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String selection = "_id = ?";
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(_ID,_id);
    contentValues.put(LAST_NO,last_no);
    long result = database.update(TABLE_NAME , contentValues , _ID + " =? " ,
            new String[]{_id});
    if (result == -1){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling the application.

Comment: I did that but still not helping.

Comment: Try adding `tools:replace="android:allowBackup"` and `android:allowBackup="false"` in application tag of manifest file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ALTER the table to Add the new LAST_NO column, as you want to preserve the existing data. That is you want to Upgrade the database and that is what the **`onUpgrade`** method is used for.

The onUpgrade method is invoked if the version number is increased. So **(1)** the first thing to do is change the version number from 1 to 2.

i.e. change `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);` to `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);`

As any new installs (as opposed to upgrades) will be at version 2, then the **`onCreate`** method should reflect the upgrade so **(2)** change it to :-

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String create_table = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( "
            + "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,"
            + RADIO_BUTTON_POSITION + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + LAST_NO + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " //<<<< ADDED FOR version 2
            + _ID + " TEXT NOT NULL)";
    db.execSQL(create_table);
}
```

- you may or may not want the DEFAULT clause

**(3)** You then need to change the **`onUpgrade`** method to ALTER the table and to **NOT** drop the table *(you would lose all the data)* and to **NOT** call the `onCreate` method *(this would fail if the table isn't dropped (if you had `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS .....` then it wouldn't fail))*.

The **`onUpgrade`** method should check if the upgrade is from version 1 to 2 and only if so should it ALTER the table. So you need to check the newVersion, passed to the method, is 2. If so then you use the execSQL method to issue the ALTER command to ADD the COLUMN. e.g. the **`onUpgrade`** method could be :-

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    /* commmented out for version 2*/
    // db.execSQL("drop Table if exists " + TABLE_NAME);
    // onCreate(db);

    /* Add upgrade for version 2 */
    if (oldVersion == 1 && newVersion == 2) {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ADD COLUMN " + LAST_NO + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
    }
}
```

The table will then be altered to include the new column.

**Additional** - Progressive upgrades :-

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    /* commmented out for version 2*/
    // db.execSQL("drop Table if exists " + TABLE_NAME);
    // onCreate(db);

    /* Add upgrade for version 2 */
    if (oldVersion < 2) {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ADD COLUMN " + LAST_NO + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
    }
    if (oldversion <3) {
       ....
    }
    /* an so on */
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly thanks. Just one question if you want to add a new column, will the condition in `onUpgrade` be  `(oldVersion == 2 && newVersion == 3)` to contain all exisiting and new changes?

Comment: @user16566034 If you want to cover numerous upgrades then you need to have a different test and ensure that the sequence of the upgrades is correct. So 1-2 would  be the first code encountered an have a test of  oldversion < 2, 2-3 would be the next code and have oldversion < 3 and so on. I didn't want to complicate matters explaining progressive upgrades but should have.

Comment: How would I put those test in code in `onUpgrade` and get that sequence of upgrades?

Comment: @user16566034 Just have the code in sequence first `if (oldversion < 2) {.....}` then `if (oldversion < 3) {....}` and so on. So the if blocks are processed from lowest to highest. Edited the answer to provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be adding a new column to the table so you need to go through the upgrade process.

To trigger an upgrade you need to increase the version given in the constructor

You currently have version `1` as the last parameter of call to the constructor's super class

```
public DBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }
```

So as this is likely your second version of the database so this value should be `2`

e.g.

```
public DBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);
    }
```

or more generically

```
 super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
```

Then the `onUpgrade` method will be called because the version number stored in the database does not match they current one you are opening it with.

Your `onUpgrade` deletes the exiting table and recreates it again but as you current `onCreate` does not add the new column `LAST_NO` this needs to be updated as well to something like

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String create_table = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( "
                + "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,"
                + RADIO_BUTTON_POSITION + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + "LAST_NO" + " INTEGER, "
                + _ID + " TEXT NOT NULL)";
        db.execSQL(create_table);

    }
```

If you want to keep existing data that is in database instead of dropping the database and recreating it in `onUpgrade` you should use the `ALTER TABLE` command there instead (But `onCreate` should always be the new schema)